# AJAX Show error in the modal form without reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two modals form in index.php, one for login and one for register. From the login modal you access the register form. I want to show in the register modal form an error without reloading the page or to redirect to another page.
I use ajax, but after submit, the page redirects to a blank page register.php and shows 1.

In register form I have an empty div

```
<div id = "error-reg"></div>
```

The register.php it is the action for form and looks like

```
 if ($count == 0) {
    if ($check == 1)
        $query = "INSERT INTO ..
    elseif ($check == 2)
        $query = "INSERT INTO ..
    else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO ..
    }

    if ($db->query($query)) {
        echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "2";
    }
} else {
    echo "3";
}
```

In js I have

```
$("#btn-rg").on('submit',function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var form=$(this);
     $.ajax({
        url : 'register.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : $('#id02').serialize(),
        success : function (msg) {
            if(msg=="1") $('#error-reg').html('success');
        },
        error: function (msg) {
             if(msg=="2") $('#error-reg').html('Error while registering.Please try again');
              if(msg=="3") $('#error-reg').html('The username already exists.');
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

In php, you just echo a number and browser would interpret it as success.

You can change your js file:

```
$("#btn-rg").on('submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var form = $(this);
     $.ajax({
        url: 'register.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#id02').serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg == "1") $('#error-reg').html('success');
            if (msg == "2") $('#error-reg').html('Error while registering.Please try again');
            if (msg == "3") $('#error-reg').html('The username already exists.');
        }
    });
});
```

Not sure it will work, you may can do that alternatively by adjusting your php file by throwing a http error code.

```
if ($count == 0) {
    if ($check == 1)
        $query = "INSERT INTO .."
    else if ($check == 2)
        $query = "INSERT INTO .."
    else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO .."
    }

    if ($db->query($query)) {
        echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "2";
        http_response_code(400);
    }
} else {
    echo "3";
    http_response_code(400);
}
```